# Drip line trial - leaking and some emitters not working

Tags: drip-system

I recently bought 15cm (6")-spaced 12mm (0.5") drip line, with a 16mm LDPE supply pipe.

As a test, I connected a 2-metre (6') run of supply pipe to a 1-metre (3') run of drip line (with a stop-end attached). I have a 2-bar pressure reducer connected between the tap and the supply pipe.

Unfortunately some water leaked from the end of the drip line and also from where the drip line connected to the LDPE supply pipe. Some of the drip line emitters were also not emitting water.

Is this happening because the overall length of pipe I used for the trial is rather short? Presumably the emitters don't have to be facing downwards in order to work effectively?

Thanks.

Comment: Drip line is very susceptible to blocking.

Comment: Your little leaks could not possibly materially affect the pressure in the line.The market is flooded with low-quality, and possibly counterfeit, drip irrigation products. I've yet to purchase any with emitters that even come close to the advertised delivery rate. Individual emitters range from 0 to 10-20 times their specs. Perhaps you should buy from vendors who cater almost exclusively to commercial growers, who obviously would find bogus product such as yours useless.

Answer (score 1):

The length makes no difference. Normally the whole line will be at the same pressure because the total discharge volume is lower than the available supply volume. A drip type emitter can face any direction; A spray type can be directed. I have used emitters very little as I have found them prone to plugging and stopping. I guess I never used an effective filter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Maybe the problem with mine is the leaks where the fittings are. I'll have to see if I can tighten them, possibly using jubilee/hose clips and see if that makes a difference. Presumably if any water leaks out then it'll affect the pressure in the line. It's a good make (John Deere) so I'd be surprised if it's a problem with the line.